# renaming files Powershell can not see

Tags: c#, c, powershell, vbscript, cmd

I have a folder of over 8000 images, they are not in the usual format and their extensions are numbers 0-9. This is used by a card ID system. each image has a file name that is a number, and the extension is part of the UID for each picture. I need to loop through copies of each image stripping leading zeros, remove the "." before the number extension and add .jpg at the end. i have had no problem copying the images. i tried to use powershell but even after importing each image powershell sees them all but when i try to rename i get an error that the file does not exist.
I would be interested to hear from anyone who may have a better method using C, VBS, or even command line. Just help me get started if i can loop through even 2 images i think i could proceed. i did have a visual basic access program doing this but the new process will reside on a server without Access or any other microsoft office tools.

Here is the code i am trying to use

```
$target =  "C:\Onecard\Onecard\onecard\" 
$Filelist = gci $target 
ForEach($i iN $Filelist){
    $BASENAME = ($i.BaseName).TRIMSTART("0")
    REN $i "$($BASENAME)" 
}
```

Comment: Show us a few of the actual file names as they are now, and what you want them to look like afterwards.

Comment: Would be helpful if you would post the code that's failing.

Comment: file example 
00000000.1 needs to be 1.jpg
88012345.4 needs to be 880123454.jpg

Comment: As @Rufus said, post the code that's failing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this suit your needs then?

```
$target =  "C:\Onecard\Onecard\onecard\"
Get-ChildItem $target | ForEach-Object{
    $newName = ($_.Name -replace "\.").TrimStart("0") + ".jpg"
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $newName 
}
```

You say that you need to change items like this

```
00000000.1 > 1.jpg 
88012345.4 > 880123454.jpg
```

What the code will do is take each file and using the full name ie: 00000000.1 remove the period, leading zeros and attach the .jpg extension. This should yeild the desired result. I would urge you to test this with copies of the files first.

The replace command uses regex so the period needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you (or whatever credentials your PS script is running under) have the appropriate rights (traversal, view contents, rename, etc.) on the the directory(ies) in question.

This little C# console app should do the trick (untested):

```
static int Main( string[] args )
{

  DirectoryInfo srcDir = new DirectoryInfo( args[0] ) ;
  DirectoryInfo tgtDir = new DirectoryInfo( args[1] ) ;

  if ( !srcDir.Exists ) throw new ArgumentException() ;
  if ( !tgtDir.Exists )
  {
    tgtDir.Create() ;
  }

  //
  // make sure we've got rights on the source directory
  //
  FileIOPermissionAccess srcRights = FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery
                                   | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read
                                   ;
  FileIOPermission srcPermission = new FileIOPermission( srcRights , srcDir.FullName ) ;
  try
  {
    srcPermission.Demand() ;
  }
  catch ( SecurityException )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Insufficient rights on source: {0}" , srcDir.FullName ) ;
    Environment.Exit(1) ;
  }

  //
  // make sure we've got rights on the target directory
  //
  FileIOPermissionAccess tgtRights     = FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess ;
  FileIOPermission       tgtPermission = new FileIOPermission( tgtRights , tgtDir.FullName ) ;
  try
  {
    tgtPermission.Demand() ;
  }
  catch ( SecurityException )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Insufficient rights on destination: {1}" , tgtDir.FullName ) ;
    Environment.Exit(1) ;
  }

  //
  // lets do the copy
  //
  Regex rxFileName = new Regex( @"^(?<stem>[0-9]+)\.(?<ext>[0-9]$" , RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture ) ;
  foreach ( FileInfo fi in srcDir.EnumerateFiles( "*.*" , SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly ) )
  {
    Match m = rxFileName.Match( fi.Name ) ;
    if ( !m.Success ) continue ;

    string stem    = m.Groups["stem"].Value ;
    string ext     = m.Groups["ext"].Value  ;
    string newName = stem + ext + ".jpg" ;
    string newPath = Path.Combine( tgtDir.FullName , newName ) ;

    fi.CopyTo( newPath , true ) ;

  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I have Domain Admin rights, i can use powershell and rename one file at a time but when i run foreach it says the file does not exist

`$target =  "C:\Onecard\Onecard\onecard\"`
`$Filelist = gci $target`
`  ForEach($i iN $Filelist){`
`  $BASENAME = ($i.BaseName).TRIMSTART("0")`
`REN $i "$($BASENAME)"`
`}`

Comment: Include your code in your question so that it can be seen by others better.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to use loop:

```
    $target = "C:\Onecard\Onecard\onecard\" 
   Get-ChildItem $target | ren -new { ($_.Name -replace "\.").TrimStart("0") + ".jpg"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module PSimagetools
Import-Module powershellPack

TRY{
$dir = "E:\SSIS\OneCard\OneCard\Images\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}


 RoboCopy \\machias\Onecard\Onecard\PICTURES  E:\SSIS\OneCard\OneCard\Images\ *.0 *.1 *.2 *.3 *.4 *.5 *.6 *.7 *.8 *.9 /XD /njh /njs /xf *.jpg *.zip

$Filelist = gci $Dir -Exclude *.jpg
foreach($File in $Filelist)
{
     Write-Verbose "Working on $file"
    $baseName = ($file.Name).Replace(".","").TrimStart("0")
    ren $file "$($baseName).jpg"


       }

              gci 'E:\SSIS\OneCard\OneCard\Images\' | Set-Imagesize -Destination \\Aroostook\CAMSEnterprise\StuPics\Test -WidthPx 351 -HeightPx 400  -overwrite -FixedSize 
    } CATCH     {
send-mailmessage -from DoNotReply@Husson.edu -to "email","email" -subject "Warning! -- One Card" -smtpserver securemail.husson.edu -body "Their has been an error processing the one card pictures please investigate!"
}          

    enter code here
```

Comment: This what i finally came up with. Works like a charm it also calls a function that was written by Author: Michal Gajda
  Blog  : http://commandlinegeeks.com/
which is a really useful tool and replaces the need for third party software (i had previously been using Image magik) Thanks for your input and i hope someone can use what i have posted here. nothing like sharing knowlege!